# An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-3.0, sqlclient

Code :

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection CON = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\stud\Documents\ronak.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

      
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Table where username= ' " + textBox1.Text + "' and password= ' " + textBox2.Text + "' ", CON);
         
    SqlDataReader sda = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    dt.Load(sda);
    if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
     {

        this.Hide();
        login2 rk = new login2();
        rk.Show();
     }
     else
     {
        MessageBox.Show("please chack you username and password");
     }
 }
```

This code is totally true but I have face some problem.

Comment: This code is definitely broken and vulnerable to SQL injection. In addition to the horrible query concatenation, it adds an extra blank in front of the text values of username and password.

Comment: This is Webforms and not asp.net mvc, or core, right? And plain text passwords are a bad idea

Comment: I'm pretty sure your table holding the user data isn't called `Table`.

Comment: what if the query did not return any rows, then your code `if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")` will throw exception.

Comment: {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection CON = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=./(LocalDB)/MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:/Users/stud/Documents/ronak.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Table where username= ' " + textBox1.Text + "' and password= ' " + textBox2.Text + "' ", CON);
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")

Comment: You have not opened the connection, do `CON.open();` before calling the Fill method.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has quite a number of different issues:

- Your connection string is missing `=` after `Data Source`
- You need to actually open the connection.
- Do not use `AttachDbFilename` instead create and connect to a normal database.
- Do not store plain-text passwords. Salt and hash them instead. Then compare the hash server-side, do not return it to the client.
- You don't need a `DataTable` or `DataAdapter`, you can just use `ExecuteScalar` to retrieve a single value.
- Dispose the connection and command with `using`.
- Do **not** inject data into your queries. Use parameters instead.

```cs
const string query = @"
Select 1
from Table
where username= @username
  and password= @password
";

using (var CON = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=ronak;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, CON))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = textBox1.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 256).Value = SaltAndHashPassword(textBox2.Text, textBox1.Text);
    CON.Open();
    var exists = cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 1;
    CON.Close();

    if (exists)
    {
        this.Hide();
        login2 rk = new login2();
        rk.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("please chack you username and password");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you forget =  after Data source in sqlConnection
Second you are using bad names for variables
Third you dont `need to use SqlCommand, you can replace it with SqlDataAdapter it`s more simple
Fourth you must use ( Using ) to dispose connection

Here`s the full code

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\stud\Documents\ronak.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connection  Timeout=30"))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter($"Select * from Table where username= '{textBox1.Text}' and password= '{textBox2.Text}' ", connection))
                {
                    adapter.Fill(table);

                    if (table.Rows.Count == 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("please chack you username and password");
                        return;
                    }
                    if (table.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
                    {
                        this.Hide();
                        login2 rk = new login2();
                        rk.Show();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```